# check if name exists in database before adding using controller function php

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, controller

I have two functions: `checkDatabase($name)` and `add`.
The first one checks if the name passed is already in the database. The next one adds if is not yet in the database. Here are my codes:

```
public function checkDatabase($name) {
        $list = $this->data_model->getCommunityList();

        foreach ($list as $sites) {
            if ($sites->name == $name) {
                return $name;
            }
        }

        return false;       
}

public function add(){
        $names = $this->input->post('add-list');

        if ($names != '') {
            if (strpos($names, "\n") == TRUE ) { //newline found
                $names = $this->input->post('add-list');
                $namesArray = explode("\n", $names);

                foreach($namesArray as $name) {
                    $checker = "";
                    $checker = $this->checkDatabase($name);
                    if ($checker == $name) {
                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('A site in your list already exists. Duplicate sites are not allowed.');</script>";
                    }

                    else {
                        $this->data_model->addCommunity($name);
                    }
                }

                $this->index();
                redirect(base_url());
            }
         }
}
```

My model:

```
public function addCommunity($name){
        $names = $this->db->escape_str($name);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO community (name) VALUES ('$name');";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $query;
}
```

My table:
[image]

The problem is my functions still add the name in the database even if it already exists. Even the SQL table says "UNIQUE", my query still accepts my input. What's wrong with my code? Help please!!!

Comment: Can we see the code where the functions are called?
Also, do you have the SQL script that created the table so we can see the constraints?

Comment: Please share your model

Comment: here:        foreach ($list as $sites) {
            if ($sites->name == $name) {
                return $name;
            }
        }..please var_dump(sites->name,$name)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert only if the record doesn't exists. You can check it before inserting in the model other than calling another function for that.

```
public function addCommunity($name){
        $names = $this->db->escape_str($name);
        $checkquery=$this->db->query("select * from community where name='$name'");
        if($checkquery->num_rows()==0)   // if there is no such a row then insert
        {
          $sql = "INSERT INTO community (name) VALUES ('$name')";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
          return $query;
       }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try in this way

```
public function checkDatabase($name) {
    $this->db->select ( 'name' );
    $this->db->from ( 'community' );
    $this->db->like ( 'name', '$name' );

    $query = $this->db->get ();

    if ($query->num_rows () == 1) {
        $row = $query->first_row ();
        return $row->name;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `where` should be used instead of `like`

Comment: No.. because we should the name in the database, the way you are checking will increase the execution time of the script and checking every name in a list of php script so the best practise is search the name in the database.

Comment: suppose i have `bira` in names table and if i enter `bir` it will not add `bir` in db instead it will give `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('A site in your list already exists. Duplicate sites are not allowed.');</script>";` but its not correct. it should add `bir` in db.